# wp_get_archives() not translating to french wpml

Tags: wordpress, translation

I am using wpml to translate a wordpress site I am building. I have created a custom theme and am using wp_get_archives() to show the archives in the blog section. When I switch to the french side of the site the dates do not get translated. Does wordpress not automatically have its own translation files on hand?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I figured it out. I had put my custom themes .mo file in both my themes language folder as well as my Wordpress language folder. All I needed to do was replace my .mo in /wp-content/languages with Wordpress' fr_FR.mo. So now both .mo files are being included, and all dates are being translated.